# Break down the sentence 喧嘩{けんか}が強{つよ}い上{うえ}に、男前{おとこまえ}

Tags: grammar, syntax, video-games

I can't get the correct translation and understand the structure of this sentence:

> けんか{kenka} 　が{ga}　つよい{tsuyoi}　うえに{ueni}、おとこまえ{otokomae}。

> 喧嘩{けんか}が強{つよ}い上{うえ}に、男前{おとこまえ}。

This is a quote said by a videogame character after winning a fight. The [sources](https://snk.fandom.com/wiki/Yashiro_Nanakase/Quotes#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20list%20of%20quotes%20for%20Yashiro,strong%2C%20I%27m%20handsome%20too.%22%20%E4%BD%95%20%7E%20%21%3F%20NANI%7E%21%3F?msclkid=82415c84cf2111ecb957e1d96d75c174) point out that this means "Not only am I strong; but handsome as well!", but I can't get to this answer analyzing the sentence.

Comment: This is one of the quotes of Yashiro Nanakase, of the videogame King of Fighters. You can find a list with its quotes and translations to English [here](https://snk.fandom.com/wiki/Yashiro_Nanakase/Quotes#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20list%20of%20quotes%20for%20Yashiro,strong%2C%20I%27m%20handsome%20too.%22%20%E4%BD%95%20~%20%21%3F%20NANI~%21%3F?msclkid=82415c84cf2111ecb957e1d96d75c174).

Comment: Also, please note that direct requests for translations are off-topic in this site. Since you invested some time and effort behind your question, this wouldn't be the case, but you would need to actually **share your analysis and point out the specific points you are struggling with**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may analyze as follows:

## Break them down

- **Kenka ga tsuyoi** = strong (in fighting)
- **ue ni** = on top of
- **otokomae** = handsome

---

## Put them together

Strong + on top of + handsome

---

## Adjust

(I am) strong + (and) on top (of that) + (I am) handsome

---

## Result

- I am strong; and on top of that I am handsome!

same as

- Not only am I strong; but handsome as well!

Comment: can you only talk a bit more about the first "break"? since "ga" is used as a particle for mark the subject that does an action, what is the purpose here?

Comment: @Kaneda are you familiar with the adjective 好き? consider the sentence チョコレートが好き. It's the same structure than 喧嘩が強い. This is a fairly common pattern Noun + が + Adjective, where the adjective is describing the noun, and there is **no** action.

Comment: @Kaneda jarmanso7's comment is spot on. For our example: "Tsuyoi" means strong and "kenka" means fighting. "Kenka tsuyoi" sounds like "strong fighting", so *something* is missing. The answer is "ga": "Kenka **ga** tsuyoi" = "strong **in** fighting". You may check [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59191/n%e3%81%8c%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d-vs-v%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8c%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d-what-form-should-be-used).